# How to save space displaying "max x \in [a,b]"?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, math-operators

[image]

I just create a summary for usage in my exam and there are a lot of information worth to be on this summary page.

`k=1,...,n` below `max` is a waste of space
(I have more than 10 of these wasted lines on the page).

Is there any way to fit `\underset{k=1,...,n}{\max}` into the borders?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome! The math operators are all set up to do this by default when using limits: simply use `\max_{k=1,\dots,n}`. Inline math defaults to the compact limit position you're looking for, and display math defaults to the underset behavior. You can force a certain positioning in either mode using `\max\limits_{k=1,\dots,n}` and `\max\nolimits_{k=1,\dots,n}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `\underset` for operator "limits": there's a better way.

With `amsmath`, the limits are automatically positioned according to the current math style (display or inline). If necessary, `\limits` and `\nolimits` can be used to manually control the positioning. But the manual adjustments should be used with care: most of the time, the default looks best.

The default for inline math is for the limits to be placed to the side. This prevents increased leading, which I believe is what you're hoping to avoid here. So just using `$\max_{k=1,\dots,n} \lvert x \rvert$` should do the job.

Here's an example showing all the possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\textwidth}{2.5in} % just for the sample

\begin{document}
Inline, default: \hfill $\max_{k=1,\dots,n} \lvert x \rvert$

Inline, \verb+\nolimits+: \hfill $\max\nolimits_{k=1,\dots,n} \lvert x \rvert$

Inline, \verb+\limits+: \hfill $\max\limits_{k=1,\dots,n} \lvert x \rvert$

Display, default:
\[\max_{k=1,\dots,n} \lvert x \rvert\]

Display, \verb+\nolimits+:
\[\max\nolimits_{k=1,\dots,n} \lvert x \rvert\]

Display, \verb+\limits+:
\[\max\limits_{k=1,\dots,n} \lvert x \rvert\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Judging by the "small" size of the `\sum` symbol, you're trying to render these expressions in inline math style. If that's correct, you may want to ask yourself if you even need to indicate the full range of `k`, or if a single subscript `k` suffices. Displaying a single index will save you a lot of space immediately. And, presumably, your readers already know that the index `k` ranges from `1` to `n`, right?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}\lvert\rvert
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}\lVert\rVert
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{@{} >{$\bfseries}l<{$} l}
Eukl.\ Norm & \norm{x}_2=\bigl[{\sum_k x_k^2}\bigr]^{1/2}\\[1ex]
Max.norm    & \norm{x}_{\infty} = \max_k \abs{x_k}\\[1ex]
$L_1$-Norm  & \norm{x}_1 = \sum_k \abs{x_k}\\
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```